# How do I get a Zenity feature in Yad?

Tags: zenity, yad

I have the following twenty-six files in a folder:

```
$ ls
a.txt  c.txt  e.txt  g.txt  i.txt  k.txt  m.txt  o.txt  q.txt  s.txt  u.txt  w.txt  y.txt
b.txt  d.txt  f.txt  h.txt  j.txt  l.txt  n.txt  p.txt  r.txt  t.txt  v.txt  x.txt  z.txt
$
```

I can use Zenity like this:

```
zenity --list --title=Test --width=275 --height=400 --column="File names" *.txt
```

and get this interface initially:

[image: Zenity list]

If I want to select a file lower down the list, say, `r.txt`, I press <kbd>r</kbd> and `r.txt` is selected.

[image: Zenity showing selection]

However, if I use Yad instead of Zenity like this:

```
yad --list --title=Test --width=275 --height=400 --column="File names" *.txt
```

pressing <kbd>r</kbd> does nothing. I have to use the arrow keys to scroll through the list until I come to `r.txt`.

My understanding is that Yad has more features than Zenity. So is there some way to get Yad to do what Zenity does?

(Tested using the repository versions of Yad and Zenity found in 18.04 and 19.10.)

Comment: On phone but you designate any column as `--searchable` or something like that. I'll post a real answer when I get home.

Comment: I would for sure use rofi (or dmenu) for such user case. It has a fantastic quick search that narrows quickly down based on substrings you type. I use it for inserting custom text snippets among others.

Comment: @DKBose Answer posted. Sorry for delay, but going to work pays for computers needed to answer questions :)

Comment: @vanadium I haven't heard of either package before and would like to learn more. If you post an answer ping me and I'll upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I came across [this](https://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/how-to-insert-code-snippets-on-the-command-line-without-executing-them) which uses `yad` to deal with snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For learning `yad` I found this great reference: [YAD - Smokey01.com](http://smokey01.com/yad/)

As mentioned in comments you want to use the option `--search-column=N`

Take the following code snippet as an example:

```bash
while true ; do
    local Selected INSTRUCTIONS
    INSTRUCTIONS="Click Icon to move and press Enter"
    Selected=$(yad --list --radiolist \
    --image="$ICON" --window-icon="$ICON" \
    --margins=10 --no-click  --search-column=4 \
    --title="$TITLE" "${GEOMETRY[@]}" \
    --text="<big><b>$TEXT</b></big> - $INSTRUCTIONS" \
    --column "Select" \
    --column "Order" \
    --column "Icon Type:HD" \
    --column "Icon name" \
    --column "Linkless name:HD" \
    --column "Modified date" \
    --column "Col Pos:NUM" \
    --column "Row Pos:NUM" \
    --button="_Alpha Sort:$ButnAlpha" \
    --button="_Linkless Sort:$ButnLinkless" \
    --button="_Oldest Date:$ButnOldest" \
    --button="_Newest Date:$ButnNewest" \
    --button="_Test:$ButnTest"  \
    --button="_Apply:$ButnApply" \
    --button="_Cancel:$ButnCancel" \
    "${IconsArr[@]}")

    Retn="$?"
```

Columns #3 and #5 are hidden but they are still counted. We want to search on Icon Name so it is column #4 as recorded here:

```bash
    --margins=10 --no-click  --search-column=4 \
```

The short `.gif` clip below shows what happens when we type:

- <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd> (then gif loops)

[image: search column.gif]