# How can I use Rofi to insert boilerplate text snippets into browser windows in an Xorg session?

Tags: scripts

I've been using [Texpander](https://github.com/leehblue/texpander) as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075019/248158) to insert boilerplate text snippets into browser windows and word processor documents in an Xorg session.

Recently, a comment by @vanadium [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186143/how-do-i-get-a-zenity-feature-in-yad#comment1982248_1186143) indicated that Rofi could be used as well:

> I would for sure use rofi (or dmenu) for such user case. It has a fantastic quick search that narrows quickly down based on substrings you type. I use it for inserting custom text snippets among others.

How do I go about using Rofi for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Requirements: `rofi`, `xclip`, and `xdotool` in an Xorg session

According to `apt show rofi`, *Rofi* is a

> window switcher, run dialog and dmenu replacement

I searched the internet and came across [User scripts](https://github.com/davatorium/rofi/wiki/User-scripts). One of the scripts listed there, *Kaomoji Rofi* is described as "a simple kaomoji picker". I took [its code](https://gitlab.com/ceda_ei/kaomoji-rofi/blob/master/kaomoji.sh) (which I don't fully understand) and modified it:

```
#!/bin/bash

selection=$(rofi -i -width 1000 -theme solarized -dmenu $@ < /home/dkb/Documents/snippets.txt)
kaomoji=$(echo $selection)
echo -n "$kaomoji" | xclip -selection clipboard
sleep 0.1
xdotool key shift+Insert
```

- Rofi doesn't feature word wrap and so having `-width 1000` or more is useful to see as much of the snippet contents because only one line is allotted to per snippet. Anything exceeding the width is represented by …
- if `-theme` isn't used, the default theme or the theme last chosen by using `rofi-theme-selector` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117948/248158) will be used.
- The snippets are in a plain text file, one snippet per line. (Running `sort -u -o $HOME/Documents/snippets.txt $HOME/Documents/snippets.txt` once in a while keeps them sorted though it isn't really necessary.)
- `sleep 0.1` and `xdotool key shift+Insert` are not essential. Users can use their preferred method to paste clipboard text.

I saved the script as *rofi-snippets.sh* in `$HOME/bin`, made it executable, and bound it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut to launch it.

Users can rapidly select the snippet of their choice by typing in one or a few characters to highlight just the one snippet and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Here's an animation illustrating the script in action:

[image: Animation showing the use of Rofi to add snippets]